# SQL random feature

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
String show = "SELECT * FROM car ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4";
```

hi there so im using netbeans to create this quiz software. I have decided to use sqlite. so whenever I click on the button start, the program goes and fetches a random row of questions from the database and displays it in a textarea. the problem is, sometimes it repeats the same question because its just randomized. i want my question to be random but each to be unique and not repeated twice. and i want a limit of 5 question after which the program should end the quiz and display a message. need help, i am a beginner at this.

Comment: Simple solution could be to keep track of the questions asked in java and then ask multiple times until you have 5 new questions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help other users that have the same question find the answers, please choose a more specific title. Also, please make your question easier to read for people who might have an answer for you by using proper capitalization and making multiple, sensible paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
....WHERE NOT (name = 'Paul' AND city = 'London')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like add another column which will have number from 1-5 or how many ever questions you want and to that you can add your question to each integer.

Now all you do is generate a unique number like this 
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/finding-unique-non-repeating-random-numbers

and the select question where number = (the generated number).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword that sure there is no repeated results in your result set.

Like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM car ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Repeat is not the same result. Repeat overall, example when they try get another 5 question they get some same question who were before

Comment: The problem is not with duplicate rows in the table but having the same row(s) returned when running the query multiple times.

Comment: yes, sir I got that, can you get the count of ran time that user clicks ```try again``` ?

Comment: then you can use ```WHERE NOT``` clause and check questions ids that earlier in select query.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, not you.

Comment: Well you need to fix your answer anyway